# Графика в Windows Forms приложении (построение геометрических фигур)

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, gdi+

Мне нужно построить квадрат, на одной стороне которого, как на основании, построен равносторонний треугольник со стороной a.
Как составить формулу для построения равностороннего треугольника по заданной стороне и заданным координатам квадрата(чтобы треугольник строился без искажения),код:

```
namespace Project1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Сводка для MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
            //
            Count = -1; // количество прямоугольников (не более 25)
            Koord = gcnew array<int>(4); // координаты прямоугольников
            tr = gcnew array<int>(4);

        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private:int Count; // количество фигур
            array <int> ^Koord; // координаты
            array <int>^tr;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;




    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;




    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;


    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::NumericUpDown^  numericUpDown1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::NumericUpDown^  numericUpDown2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::NumericUpDown^  numericUpDown3;




    protected:














    protected:

    protected:





    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

    #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->numericUpDown1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::NumericUpDown());
            this->numericUpDown2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::NumericUpDown());
            this->numericUpDown3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::NumericUpDown());
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->numericUpDown1))->BeginInit();
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->numericUpDown2))->BeginInit();
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->numericUpDown3))->BeginInit();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
            this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
            this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(365, 177);
            this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
            this->pictureBox1->Paint += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventHandler(this, &MyForm::pictureBox1_Paint);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(202, 205);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(176, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 5;
            this->label1->Text = L"Задайте сторону треугольника а:";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(11, 259);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(185, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 6;
            this->button1->Text = L"нарисовать ";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(202, 244);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(246, 13);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 11;
            this->label2->Text = L"Задайте координаты расположения квадрата: ";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->AutoSize = true;
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(216, 269);
            this->label3->Name = L"label3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(14, 13);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 14;
            this->label3->Text = L"X";
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this->label4->AutoSize = true;
            this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(263, 269);
            this->label4->Name = L"label4";
            this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(14, 13);
            this->label4->TabIndex = 15;
            this->label4->Text = L"Y";
            // 
            // numericUpDown1
            // 
            this->numericUpDown1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(240, 221);
            this->numericUpDown1->Name = L"numericUpDown1";
            this->numericUpDown1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(37, 20);
            this->numericUpDown1->TabIndex = 16;
            // 
            // numericUpDown2
            // 
            this->numericUpDown2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(205, 285);
            this->numericUpDown2->Name = L"numericUpDown2";
            this->numericUpDown2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(37, 20);
            this->numericUpDown2->TabIndex = 17;
            // 
            // numericUpDown3
            // 
            this->numericUpDown3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(248, 285);
            this->numericUpDown3->Name = L"numericUpDown3";
            this->numericUpDown3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(37, 20);
            this->numericUpDown3->TabIndex = 18;
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(450, 321);
            this->Controls->Add(this->numericUpDown3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->numericUpDown2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->numericUpDown1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
            this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::FixedSingle;
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->numericUpDown1))->EndInit();
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->numericUpDown2))->EndInit();
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->numericUpDown3))->EndInit();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
    #pragma endregion



    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        Koord[0] = int(numericUpDown1->Value);
        Koord[1] = int(numericUpDown2->Value);
        Koord[2] = int(numericUpDown3->Value);
        tr[0] = int(numericUpDown1->Value);
        tr[1] = int(numericUpDown2->Value);
        tr[2] = int(numericUpDown3->Value);
        pictureBox1->Refresh();

    }
    private: System::Void pictureBox1_Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) {
        int X1 = Koord[1];
        int Y1 = Koord[2];
        int X2 = Koord[0];
        int Y2 = Koord[0];
        int x1 = tr[1];
        int y1 = tr[2];
        int x2 = tr[0];
        int y2 = tr[0];
        int x3 = tr[1] + tr[0] + tr[1]/2 + tr[0]/2;
        int y3 = double((tr[0] + tr[2]/2));
        e->Graphics->DrawRectangle(Pens::Black, X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
        e->Graphics->FillRectangle(Brushes::Yellow, X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
        e->Graphics->DrawPolygon(Pens::Black, gcnew array<Point>{
            Point((x1 + x2), y1),
                Point((x1 + x2), (y1 + y2)),
                Point(x3, y3)
        });
        e->Graphics->FillPolygon(Brushes::Green, gcnew array<Point>{
            Point((tr[1] + tr[0]), tr[2]),
                Point((tr[1] + tr[0]), (tr[2] + tr[0])),
                Point(x3, y3)

        });
        String^st1 = "Квадрат с равносторонним треугольником";
        e->Graphics->DrawString(st1,this->Font,Brushes::Black,tr[0],tr[0]+60)
        ;

    }

    };
}
```

Comment: Если вас интересует формула, то для чего в вопросе код? Если проблема с кодом, то какая именно?

Comment: я же написал,что проблема в том ,у меня происходит искажение картины при разных координатах x и y расположения квадрата.

Comment: Если посмотрите на свой вопрос (который в текущем виде совсем не вопрос, а непонятно что), то увидите, что он закрыт, как требующий правки. Так что вопрос "к чему ваш вопрос" вам впору задать себе лично, раз уж вы не ознакомились с тем, как хорошо и правильно задавать вопросы.

Comment: Я думаю,в моём случае дело не в этом,дело в том,вы прикрываясь предлогом "не вопрос,а не понятно,что" не желаете мне помогать мало того вы мешаете мне получать ответ не понятно почему,тот кто предложил правку моего вопроса лично не прокомментировал что в моём вопросе не понятно.

Comment: Чтобы получить ответ, нужно задать вопрос. А этого у вас и нет.

Comment: Кстати, людей, закрывших вопрос, как непонятный, не 1, а как минимум 5 человек, плюс я. Так что вам стоит задуматься. а действительно ли все так понятно в "вопросе", как вам кажется. А ответ вы будете получать очень долго, вопрос-то закрыт, так что тут я совсем не мешаю, а совсем наоборот - задал уточняющие вопросы, чтобы вытянуть из вас, в чем именно проблема. Но раз вы такой умный, то ждите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Треугольник можно построить с помощью `DrawPolygon` (и заполнить соответственно `FillPolygon`)

Если даны координаты двух вершин равностороннего треугольника `(x1,y1)` и `(x2,y2)`, то координаты третьей стороны рассчитать несложно:

```
//вектор разности
dx = (x2 - x1)
dy = (y2 - y1)
//средняя точка
mx = (x1 + x2) / 2
my = (x1 + x2) / 2
//перпендикулярный вектор
px = -dy
py = dx
//третья вершина
x3 = mx + px * Sqrt(3) / 2
y3 = my + py * Sqrt(3) / 2
// ещё зеркальная вершина, если знаки + заменить на -
```